# What is the switch in Windows schtasks for ExecutionTimeLimit in the xml file?

Tags: windows, task, scheduler, windows-task-scheduler

Windows schtasks.exe:
What is the equivalent command line switch for ExecutionTimeLimit in schtasks. In the Edit Tasks dialog it is "Stop tasks if it runs longer than".
I tried /ET end time and /DU duration but they imply a repetition. I only want a task to run once and then be killed x minutes later.

Answer (score 4):

Not a perfect solution , but you can use /XML option of schtasks

> schtasks /Create /tn jobname  /XML Path_of_xml

Within the xml file you should able to use ExecutionTimeLimit to specify the time you want to kill the job .

You can get sample xml by export a exist job to get reference

> schtasks /Query /tn jobname /XML > Path_of_xml

Comment: Nope, doesn't work if you change ExecutionTimeLimit in XML and then create task. It is automatically sets to 259200S.

Answer (score 0):

Using the Powershell it is possible to create a task where you can modify ExecutionTimeLimit to your value.

```
$MyPathToFile = 'C:\Path\File.exe'
$hour = '20:00:00'
$user = 'MyDomain\MyUserName'
$password = '123321Password'
$MyTask = 'MyTask'

$MyExecutionTimeLimit = '01:00:00' # HH:MM:SS

$trigger = New-ScheduledTaskTrigger -Daily -At $hour
$action = New-ScheduledTaskAction -Execute $MyPathToFile
$settingsSet = New-ScheduledTaskSettingsSet -ExecutionTimeLimit $MyExecutionTimeLimit
$task = New-ScheduledTask  -Action $action  -Trigger $trigger  -Settings $settingsSet 
Register-ScheduledTask -TaskName $MyTask -InputObject $task -User $user -Password $password
```